# How to hide visibility of table row with php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a simple html table:

```
                                    <style>
    .demo {
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<table class="demo">
    <caption>Table 1</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Unit Type</th>
        <th>Description of packages and goods</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $variable1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $variable2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $variable3; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $variable4; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $variable5; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $variable6; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Between  there is variables from PHP side which will provide information to table cells.

**Question:** Is it possible to hide table row which has empty variables and show only row with variables that are not empty?

**The problem now:** Row that is empty is displaying border and style and if its empty without information it looks bad and i want to hide those rows that does not consist any information.

Comment: check if its empty, only echo if its not.

Comment: If there would not be any variables the style of the table still would display. I need hide whole row wstarting from tr and eding tr tag. If you understood that maybe you could give me an example how i could achieve that?

Comment: so check var1 to 3 if not empty echo if they all are empty dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not 100% sure, but i believe this is what you are asking, if not, add a comment below.

```
if(!empty($variable1.$variable2.$variable3) ){
 echo "<tr>
        <td>$variable1</td>
        <td>$variable2</td>
        <td>$variable3</td>
    </tr>";
}else{
//do nothing
}
```